# Google Cloud Composer authentication for BigQueryHook

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to make use of the BigQueryHook but I am unable to get the service account authentication working.

I've followed the steps provided by Google and have copied the JSON file into the data/ directory in the environment's GCS bucket. 
The Airflow Connection details have been filled in:

JSON Keyfile Path: /home/airflow/gcs/data/my-key-file.json

Keyfile JSON: content of the JSON file

Scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Error in stackdriver:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 374, in process_file m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath) File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source module = _load(spec) File "", line 684, in _load File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked File "", line 678, in exec_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/cloud_sql_to_bq.py", line 141, in  df = get_config() File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/cloud_sql_to_bq.py", line 71, in get_config bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=bq_hook._get_field("my-project"), credentials=bq_hook._get_credentials()) File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 103, in _get_credentials key_path, scopes=scopes) File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 209, in from_service_account_file filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri']) File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 71, in from_filename with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file: **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/airflow/gcs/data/my-key-file.json'**

Any idea why it can't see the JSON file?

Comment: You put your key file in a GCS bucket but you put the JSON Keyfile Path pointing to your local. Why? Also, if you put the content of the JSON file, you can just remove the value of JSON Keyfile Path.

Comment: @RyanTheCoder I was following the Cloud Composer documentation provided by Google which states: 
in Keyfile Path, enter the local file path on the Airflow worker to the JSON keyfile's location, such as /home/airflow/gcs/data/keyfile.json. 
I deleted the path leaving only the JSON content and it now works, thanks.